# Firebase- Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'

Tags: ios, firebase

I have downloaded it already and added it to my Xcode Project I did copy items if needed as well .. I do not understand why I am still getting this error. I have FIRApp.configure() in my app delegate... Any tips? Thank you in advance.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication,
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)
            -> Bool {
                UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

                FIRApp.configure()
                return true
        }
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Add to the project
2. Click on it:

[image]

3. On the right sidebar from Xcode, mark the `Target Membership` option:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1**

Make sure your google service plist called `GoogleServices-Info.plist`. If it's not then it won't work.

**Solution 2**

If it is still not working then just create `Resource Folder` in Xcode and then copy the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` inside the `Resource folder`. Now `Run` your project. I hope this helps you.

[image: See this image]

Comment: I had to delete that goolge.plist because I had already downloaded a google.plist before that. I used the original one I first downloaded and it worked! Thanks for the help though!

Comment: By moving the GoogleService-Info.plist into Resource Folder works for me. Happy Coding @Frank Boccia

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. EDIT: Got it. Created an answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried so many copy paste methods even creating/placing plist file in the Resource folder and nothing worked :(

sometimes, only using original plist file was best indicator of working but this is the best solution that worked 100% every time I use Xcode (8 - 9)/swift and Firebase together:

1. Go to your project settings
2. Press on Build Phases
3. Press on Copy Bundle Resources (to expand)
4. Drag the your GoogleServices-Info.plist into this folder
5. now Run the project and it should work :D

Answer (score 0):

I was making `FIRApp.configure()` from two different file/places, due to which app was crashing.

You need to call only one time.