# Firebase crash. xcode 9. No googleservice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Why does the error say `Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'` but I have it in my Xcode project directory, matching with my bundle id?

**Error:**

```
2017-09-22 13:12:00.728562+0300 Descent Calculator 2.0[874:187526] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2017-09-22 13:12:00.938617+0300 Descent Calculator 2.0[874:187250] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2017-09-22 13:12:01.414789+0300 Descent Calculator 2.0[874:187538] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2017-09-22 13:12:01.415446+0300 Descent Calculator 2.0[874:187538] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2017-09-22 13:12:01.499943+0300 Descent Calculator 2.0[874:187250] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.
```

First throw call stack:

```
(0x184713d38 0x183c28528 0x184713c80 0x1040e91b0 0x104086354 0x1040864ac 0x18db92050 0x18dd85898 0x18dd8a6e4 0x18e018454 0x18e2e81f0 0x18e0180b8 0x18e018928 0x18e7816e8 0x18e78158c 0x18e4fd9c0 0x18e692fc8 0x18e4fd870 0x18e2e7850 0x18dd88e28 0x18e18c6ec 0x186db5768 0x186dbe070 0x1056b545c 0x1056c1b74 0x186de9a04 0x186de96a8 0x186de9c44 0x1846bc358 0x1846bc2d8 0x1846bbb60 0x1846b9738 0x1845da2d8 0x18646bf84 0x18db86880 0x104087aec 0x1840fe56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Aswell when I remove `FirebaseApp.configure()` from `AppDelegate.swift` my app wont crash anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution posted in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250528/firebase-could-not-locate-configuration-file-googleservice-info-plist)

Step 1: Click on the GoogleService-info.plist

Step 2: On the right panel, go in the Target Membership. See if it checked.

Step 3: Click the checkbox, [image]

I have tested with xcode 9.Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

Had this after upgrading to the latest xCode, try this

Close Xcode, open terminal, before anything else, type: “defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode” (this addresses your Xcode settings) open Xcode and your project should work normally

Comment: Didn't work. Only reverted my Xcode back to original settings.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new app with a different bundle identifier and forgot to create a new GoogleService-info.plist - drove me nuts until I came across this post.