# SIGABRT Error due to FirebaseApp.configure()

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase

Whenever I download the Google info plist file to my project and put it just under the infoplist, use pod init, set the pod 'Firebase/Core' etc., add the configure function to my AppDelegate after importing Firebase, I get the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". I've tried everything, created another simple project, which was treated the same way as the main one and I still got this error, which signifies that the origin of the error comes from "FirebaseApp.configure()". Please, help me, I'm literally dying.

Comment: Have you turned on "break on all exceptions" in your Xcode project? (It's potentially generating errors before it hits the SIGABRT.)

Comment: No, but I tried to set a breakpoint on "FirebaseApp.configure()" which gave me "breakpoint 1.1" response

Comment: @JohnParker I did it now, it says Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'. I don't understand this. My file is right in the folder, right beneath the info.plist. It's just impossible, I already tried to put it and pods in different folders to cancel out possible causes of the error

Comment: @JohnParker Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated! The cause of the problem was that I did not tick "Target membership", good luck and thanks again! P.S. for anyone with the same problem, I'm leaving a referral to the thread that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250528/firebase-could-not-locate-configuration-file-googleservice-info-plist

Comment: Yeah, that would have been my next suggestion. Glad you managed to get it sorted. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happened to me too but my issue was not the target.

How i solved my error was that i ensured that the app is part of a firebase project. Downloaded the latest GoogleInfo.plist file and replaced the one that was already in the project and it no longer crashed again.